# clearRect not working

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas

I'm doing a Pong game in javascript in order to learn making games, and I want to make it object oriented.

I can't get `clearRect` to work. All it does is draw a line that grows longer.
Here is the relevant code:

```
function Ball(){
    this.radius = 5;
    this.Y = 20;
    this.X = 25;
    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
        ctx.fill();
    };
}

var ball = new Ball();

function draw(){
    player.draw();
    ball.draw();
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
    draw();
    ball.X++;
}
```

I've tried to put the `ctx.clearRect` part in the `draw()` and `ball.draw()` functions and it doesn't work.
I also tried `fillRect` with white but it gives the same results. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you set this up on jsFiddle to help explain *draw a line that grows longer*?

Comment: I tried it earlier and couldn't get it to work there, I'll give it another try.

Comment: I don't know how to use JSFiddle, nothing from the javascript piece gets included.
I saved the code there anyway maybe you can get it to work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/25qWe/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your *real* problem is you are not closing your circle's path.

Add `ctx.beginPath()` before you draw the circle.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur6qU/).

Also, some tips...

- Your assets should not be responsible for drawing themselves (their `draw()` method). Instead, perhaps define their visual properties (is it a circle? radius?) and let your main render function handle `canvas` specific drawing (this also has the advantage that you can switch your renderer to regular DOM elements or WebGL further down the track easily).
- Instead of `setInterval()`, use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). Support is not that great at the moment so you may want to shim its functionality with `setInterval()` or the recursive `setTimeout()` pattern.
- Your `clearRect()` should be passed the dimensions from the `canvas` element (or have them defined somewhere). Including them in your rendering functions is akin to *magic numbers* and could lead to a maintenance issue further down the track.

Comment: Wow, that was unexpectedly simple.
What exactly does that code do?

Comment: the "viewport.width = viewport.width" part

I mean clearRect explains itself, I dont get what the other one does to clear the canvas.
And thanks for the tips. =)

Comment: @hustlerinc It's a bit of a hack. Basically, it relies in the `canvas` renderer clearing its contents when its dimensions change.

Comment: Ok I see, and now that i added beginPath clearRect works again, I actually had both begin and closePath but removed them to see if it broke anything (before the circle was moving) since nothing changed I left it like that :P.
What is best for performance do you know? clearRect, fillRect with color or the hack?

Comment: @hustlerinc IIRC, the hack is slower. It's also a hack, so I'd stick with `clearRect()`. You could also be like John Carmack and use [*adaptive tile refresh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_tile_refresh), but it isn't necessary with today's computers (jokes aside, it can be fun keeping track of where all objects *were* and only rendering the differences).

Comment: @alex, about the first tip, how you could do it? A renderer with a switch like structure to detect the object type and them use their properties to render it?

Comment: @JCM That'd be one way of doing it. Sometimes I like to put a `getDrawDescriptor()` on my game objects which tells the renderer *how* it should paint the element, but never using direct Canvas API calls.

Comment: @alex, Thank you very much! ``viewport.width = viewport.width;`` is so powerful!

Comment: Poor answer. Here's why: "Setting the canvas width to itself not only clears the canvas, it clears all canvas state. This means it clears the transformation matrix, the current clipping region, and all of the following attributes: strokeStyle, fillStyle, globalAlpha, lineWidth, lineCap, lineJoin, miterLimit, shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY, shadowBlur, shadowColor, globalCompositeOperation, font, textAlign, and textBaseline." From http://simonsarris.com/blog/346-how-you-clear-your-canvas-matters

Use fillRect until you can fix your problem; otherwise you may introduce other unintended bugs.

Comment: @sws This answer was written for this question. I agree it shouldn't be used.