# clear Rect doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I would like to add to a drawing program buttons with different functions. But I got problems with the first one, of course. I'm trying to have a button to clear the entire canvas. But somehow it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


var cb_canvas = null;
var cb_ctx = null;
var cb_lastPoints = null;
var cb_easing = 0.4;

// Setup event handlers
window.onload = init;
function init(e) {
cb_canvas = document.getElementById("cbook");

cb_lastPoints = Array();

if (cb_canvas.getContext) {
    cb_ctx = cb_canvas.getContext('2d');
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    cb_ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    cb_ctx.beginPath();

    cb_canvas.onmousedown = startDraw;
    cb_canvas.onmouseup = stopDraw;
    cb_canvas.ontouchstart = startDraw;
    cb_canvas.ontouchstop = stopDraw;
    cb_canvas.ontouchmove = drawMouse;
}
}


function startDraw(e) {
if (e.touches) {
    // Touch event
    for (var i = 1; i <= e.touches.length; i++) {
        cb_lastPoints[i] = getCoords(e.touches[i - 1]); // Get info for 
finger #1
    }
}
else {
    // Mouse event
    cb_lastPoints[0] = getCoords(e);
    cb_canvas.onmousemove = drawMouse;
}

return false;
}

// Called whenever cursor position changes after drawing has started
function stopDraw(e) {
e.preventDefault();
cb_canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

function drawMouse(e) {
if (e.touches) {
    // Touch Enabled
    for (var i = 1; i <= e.touches.length; i++) {
        var p = getCoords(e.touches[i - 1]); // Get info for finger i
        cb_lastPoints[i] = drawLine(cb_lastPoints[i].x, cb_lastPoints[i].y, 
p.x, p.y);
    }
}
else {
    // Not touch enabled
    var p = getCoords(e);
    cb_lastPoints[0] = drawLine(cb_lastPoints[0].x, cb_lastPoints[0].y, p.x,     
p.y);
}
cb_ctx.stroke();
cb_ctx.closePath();
cb_ctx.beginPath();

return false;
}

// Draw a line on the canvas from (s)tart to (e)nd
function drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY) {
cb_ctx.moveTo(sX, sY);
cb_ctx.lineTo(eX, eY);
    return { x: eX, y: eY };
}

// Get the coordinates for a mouse or touch event
function getCoords(e) {
if (e.offsetX) {
        return { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };
    }
    else if (e.layerX) {
        return { x: e.layerX, y: e.layerY };
    }
    else {
        return { x: e.pageX - cb_canvas.offsetLeft, y: e.pageY -     
cb_canvas.offsetTop };
}
}

$("clear").onclick=function(){clearAll()};

function clearAll() {
        var canvas = $("#cbook");
        var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
}

});



</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="cbook" width="500" height="333"></canvas>


<button id="clear">Clean Up</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743027/clearrect-not-working

Comment: hey, i've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJbwL/1/) and made you code valid. the function `init()` was used before it was declared, also you had some other minor issues. Does this already fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much right, there are a couple of problems...

```
$("clear").onclick=function(){clearAll()};
```

Should probably read

```
$("#clear").click(clearAll);
```

You needed to mark the selector as an id and also you were trying to put a native element event on a jQuery object.

The other problem is similar you are using the jQuery object containing a canvas instead of the native element, instead change...

```
var canvas = $("#cbook");
var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

To...

```
var canvas = $("#cbook");
var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.get(0).width, canvas.get(0).height);
```

Or more simply...

```
var canvas = $("#cbook").get(0);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

A fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/zZhfE/

Oh and totally forgot, the `window.onload` handler is unnecessary as you are running it within the document ready function of jQuery everything should be ready to go anyway. I just moved everything out of the function and removed the `window.onload` handler.

Comment: Good catch on the window.onload - I missed that.

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should 'accept' it - click on the tick that appears to the left of the answer when you move your mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three main issues with your code. First, you're mixing and matching Javascript and jQuery, and it's causing issues (when working with Canvas, try and stick to vanilla Javascript).

You're not getting the context in the `clearAll()` function because you're trying to use jQuery:

```
var canvas = $("#cbook");
```

When you should be using plain ol' JS, like in your drawing function:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cbook");
```

Secondly, you're calling the clear function like this:

```
$("clear").onclick=function(){clearAll()};
```

When it should be this:

```
$("#clear").on('click', function(){clearAll()});
```

(note the `#` before `clear` - you need to use this to refer to the ID of an element.)

Finally, you're looking for the first instance of a canvas inside a canvas, which won't work:

```
 var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
```

All you need is:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Here's a working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hGjDR/