# Javascript Basic Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm a total beginner with coding just in general. This is also my first time trying to do something with js; I want to animate a bunch of squares to move towards a certain point on the page. I googled a bunch of things, and I wrote this, but it doesn't work; can anybody tell me why this isn't working?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var enemies =[];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var randomX = Math.abs(Math.random());
  var randomY = Math.abs(Math.random());
  if (randomX > 100 && randomX < 1200){
    if (randomX%2 == 0){
      randomX = 140;
    } else {
      randomX = 1281;
    }
  }
  if (randomY > 100 && randomY < 75){
    if (randomY%2 == 0){
      randomY = 15;
    } else{
      randomY = 560;
    }
  }
  var enemy = new Enemy(randomX,randomY,0,0);
  enemies.push(enemy);
}

var Enemy = function(x,y,velx,vely){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velx = 0;
  this.vely = 0;
}

Enemy.prototype.update = function (){
  var tx = 650 - this.x;
  var ty = 250 - this.y;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx + ty*ty);
  this.velx = (tx/dist);
  this.vely = (ty/dist);

  if (dist > 0){
    this.x += this.velx;
    this.y += this.vely;
  }
};

Enemy.prototype.render = function(){

  context.fillStyle = #000000;
  context.rect(this.x,this.y,25,25);
  context.fill();
};

function render(){
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++){
    var one = enemies[i];
    context.clearRect(one.x,one.y,25,25);
    one.update();
    one.render();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

Comment: context.fillStyle = '#000000'; - add quotes here, and re-try....

Comment: thanks, I totally missed that! But it's still not working :(

Comment: What sort of results are you actually seeing? Can you be more specific about what is or isn't working?

Comment: After I changed my code according to user's advice, I now see one black square with afterimages...so I guess I'm clearing the canvas incorrectly. What I was trying to do though, was having 10 squares randomly placed near the edges that moved towards the centre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this `var Enemy = function...` syntax, the `Enemy` class declaration needs to be placed before any `new Enemy(...)` constructor call. And the color code must be surrounded by parenthesis.

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive), so your rectangles are almost stacked on top of each other.

You are not closing the path in `Enemy.prototype.render`, that's why it is not cleared. (Similar problem here: [clearRect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743027/clearrect-not-working))

(If you clear the whole canvas, you don't need to clear each rectangle individually, so you can remove the `context.clearRect(one.x, one.y, 25, 25);` line in the render function.)

**edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/f7vgpdko/8/

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you know why this is only working for one square though? :/