# Javascript Canvas Redrawing But I See Previously Drawn Rectangles

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to keep redrawing rectangles on HTML canvas as if I am selecting a specific region.

When I move my mouse pointer (while pressing down the mouse key) I call `redraw` which clears the canvas and redraws a rectangle corresponding to the globally stored coordinates.

Since canvas is cleared for every mouse mouse event I expected to get only one rectangle in the canvas but I got too many rectangles.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="image" width="0" height="0" style="background-color: orange"></canvas>
<script>
var mousedown = false;
var x1;
var y1;
var x2;
var y2;
document.getElementById("image").onmousedown = function(e) {
    mousedown = true;
    x1 = e.offsetX;
    y1 = e.offsetY;
    console.log(e.offsetX);
    console.log(e.offsetY);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("image")
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    console.log('clean');
}
document.getElementById("image").onmouseup = function(e){
    mousedown = false;
}
document.getElementById("image").onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (mousedown) {
        x2 = e.offsetX;
        y2 = e.offsetY;
        redraw()
    }
}

function redraw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("image")
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.rect(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1));
    context.stroke();
}
</script>
```

And the result is:

[image]

Why do I get so many rectangles and how can I get the last one?
(Or how can I do it more efficiently without any libraries?)

Comment: Can you please update problem with console.log value of canvas.width and canvas.height?

Comment: Why did you set cavas like this width="0" height="0"?

Comment: @artgb I logged and checked but I think they are not changing...

Comment: @artgb Ah, it needs to be changed according to an image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not on the clearRect method, the problem is that you need to begin a Path when you wish to draw on the canvas.

Add `context.beginPath();` above context.rect();

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gugalondon/sp9qb04p/12/)

Some great questions that have already been answered here:
[clearRect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743027/clearrect-not-working)

Also these articles are great for canvas manipulation:
http://cheatsheetworld.com/programming/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet/
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much!